# awk: find smallest 10 values from column

Tags: awk

I have a file that is arranged like so:

```
a  123
b 45
c -23
d 166
```

I'm new to awk and I want to find the ten (or x) lowest numbers in column 2 and print these rows in a new file.

Currently we use the following code and eyeball the results to see if we have roughly ten. If not, we change the -5.0 to something else and so on:

```
cat input.txt | awk '{if($2 < -5.0) {print $1" "$2}}' >> output.txt
```

Comment: If the list contains several records with the same numbers (among the lowest), do you want to preserve the first records or the last records?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily without AWK:

```
$ sort -nk 2 input.txt | head -10 > output.txt
```

It sorts the input file and prints the first 10 lines (with the lowest values in column 2).  This may not be suitable if your input file is especially large.  This `sort` probably uses an O(*N* log *N*) sorting algorithm (for *N* lines of input).

---

If you only wanted the minimum, a solution in AWK would be a one-liner.  It is a bit trickier in this case because you must maintain more than one lowest value.  Try something like this:

**lowest.awk**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{if (X=="") X=10; s=0}
{ # insert new value in order
    for (i=0; i<s && $2>a[i]; ++i);
    if (s==X && i==s) next
    for (j=s; j>i; --j) {
        a[j] = a[j-1]
        b[j] = b[j-1]
    }
    a[i] = $2
    b[i] = $0
    if (s<X) s++
}
END{ # print stored lines
    for (i=0; i<s; ++i)
        print b[i]
}
```

To run this on the command line:

```
$ awk -f lowest.awk infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

You can specify the number *X* of lowest values to print from the command line with `-v X=10`:

```
$ awk -v X=10 -f lowest.awk infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

But 10 is the default.

This compares each value (in column 2) with each element of the array `a`, and inserts the new value where needed.  The array `b` stores the full line (`$0`) to be printed at the end.  The (used) size of `a` and `b` is `s`.

Normally, you should iterate through the entries in an array with something like `for (i in a)`, but in this case, there is one extra entry at `a[s]` which must be ignored when printing the results, hence the `for (i=0; i<s; ++i)` format in the `END` block.

In the worst case, each of the *N* values are compared with *X* values in `a`.  So this is O(*XN*), which is an improvement on the O(*N* log *N*) `sort` version.  Also, it requires less memory because you are only storing O(*X*) values instead of all *N* lines in memory.

Notice that this maintains order by insertion.  Where *X*=*N*, you are keeping all values and listing them in order---in other words sorting.  The O(*XN*) formula approaches O(*N*<sup>2</sup>) as *X* approaches *N*, which is the complexity of an insertion sort algorithm.  So this AWK version is only more efficient than an O(*N* log *N*) sort-based approach where *X* is much less than *N*.

Comment: UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`.  The `sort` command will read the file which saves pushing a possibly big file down one of the two pipes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point.  I was copying the OP's line to start with.  Also worth mentioning is that AWK can take input file as an argument too.

Comment: It's easy to get suckered into doing something less than satisfactory because the OP did the same thing — I've been caught many times in a similar way.  Less so recently; I'm aware of the issue now.

Answer (score 1):

@e0k's `sort|head` is the right UNIX solution in general but if you must use awk for some reason then with GNU awk for sorted_in:

```
$ awk -v x=2 '{a[NR]=$2; b[NR]=$0}
    END{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"; for (i in a) if (x-->0) print b[i] }' file
c -23
b 45

$ awk -v x=3 '{a[NR]=$2; b[NR]=$0}
    END{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"; for (i in a) if (x-->0) print b[i] }' file
c -23
b 45
a  123
```

Comment: This is more terse (and easier to read) than my AWK version. It does essentially the same thing as the `sort|head`, storing the entire input file in memory, sorting it, then printing the first `x` lines.  I know the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` sets the iteration order, but when does AWK actually sort it?  Does it sort it when you use `in`?  Or does it place the keys in a hash table in such a way that it can easily pull them out later in order?  Depending on how it's implemented, using a hash table to sort like this could be fast (but use more memory).

Comment: It sorts it when you do `in` because until you set "sorted_in" it doesn't even know what order you want it sorted in and you could set that 20 times before you actually use it. You'd have to check the gawk manual and/or contact the implementer for more implementation details.